# Is it possible for a function to have two Records with function values with the same parameters as arguments?

Tags: typescript, types

I am trying to create a function that can receive two Records, where:

- the second one depends on the first one and where the two Records have the same keys
- they both have functions as values with the same parameters, but different return types.

I have tried the following (and its many variations):

```js
export const withGenericLogging = (
  logger: Logger,
  component: string,
  subcomponent: string,
) => <
  Keys extends string,
  ObjFn extends (...args: any[]) => unknown,
  Obj extends Record<Keys, ObjFn>,
  Mappers extends Record<Keys, (...args: Parameters<ObjFn>) => unknown>,
>(
  obj: Obj,
  mappers: Mappers,
) =>
  Object.keys(obj).reduce<Obj>(
    (acc, key) => {
      if (typeof obj[key] !== 'function') {
        return acc;
      }

      const mapper = mappers?.[key]

      acc[key] = withLogging(
        logger,
        component,
        subcomponent ? `${subcomponent}.${key}` : key,
      )(obj[key], mapper);

      return acc;
    },
    { ...obj },
  );
```

Note: The implementation of `withLogging`, `Logger` and `logger` is irrelevant to this issue.

This works nicely, as the typescript knows that if I do the following:

```js
const create = (id: string) => 'value'

const repository = withGenericLogging(
  log,
  'Module',
  'Submodule'
)(
  { create },
  { create: id => 'mappedId' },
);
```

The following will happen:

- `repository` will fully inherit the types of `obj` (it will the type `{ create: (id: string) => string }`, as intended)
- the IDE will provide some sort of type support for the `mappers` parameter (the `create` key in `{ create: id => 'mappedId' }` is suggested by the IDE)
- the `id` in `id => 'mappedId'` is of type `any`, which should be of type `string`

Would it be possible for `withGenericLogging` to provide:

- support type inference to its returned value (in the example above: `repository`)
- support for the key type for the `mappers` (should be the same keys as `obj`)
- support for the the Parameters of the right-hand-side function of the `mappers` Record, which should be the same parameters as the right-hand-side function of the `obj` Record (as in, if `obj` is `{ create: (id: string) => Promise<void> }`, `mappers` should be `{ create: (id: string) => unknown }`)
- only a generic way of handling types, rather than a fixed one (`obj` should support any type of `Record<string, (...args: unknown[]) => unknown>`, rather than a fixed `type Something = { create: (id: string) => Promise<void> }`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution

I have found the solution to my question (after many iterations):

### Part 1: Defining a generic MapperFunction type

I needed to infer the value or parameters of the function each key of the `mappers` object and use them in order to create the mapping function. So I made this:

```js
type MapperFunction<T> = T extends (...args: infer Params) => unknown
  ? (...args: Params) => unknown
  : (arg: T) => unknown;
```

Which allows me to create a function that has the arguments `Params` or the given `T` when given an argument to `MapperFunction`.

This allows me to create mapping functions, such as:

```js
const create = (id: string) => 'value'
const value = 'value'

const mapperFunctionForCreate: MapperFunction<typeof create> = id => ({ mappedId: id })
const mapperFunctionForValue: MapperFunction<typeof value> = arg => ({ mappedId: arg })
```

Where:

- `mapperFunctionForCreate` has the type `(id: string) => unknown` (as intended)
- `mapperFunctionForValue` has the type `(arg: string) => unknown` (as intended)

This solved the 1st of my problem.

### Part 2: Defining a generic MapperFunctionsObject type

The 2nd part of my problem (defining a generic object with keys `Keys` and mapper functions as value) was solved by doing the following:

```js
type MapperFunctionsObject<T> = T extends Record<string | number | symbol, unknown>
  ? { [P in keyof T]: MapperFunction<T[P]> }
  : never;
```

This allows me to do the following:

```js
const obj = {
  create: (id: string) => 'value'
};

const mapperFunctionsObject: MapperFunctionsObject<typeof obj> = {
  create: id => ({ mappedId: id })
};
```

Where `mapperFunctionsObject.create` has the type `(id: string) => unknown` (as intended).

This allows me to put together the following function:

```js
type MapperFunction<T> = T extends (...args: infer Params) => unknown
  ? (...args: Params) => unknown
  : (arg: T) => unknown;

type MapperFunctionsObject<T> = T extends Record<string | number | symbol, unknown>
  ? { [P in keyof T]: MapperFunction<T[P]> }
  : never;

export const withGenericLogging = (
  logger: Logger,
  component: string,
  subcomponent?: string,
) => <
  Key extends string,
  Value,
  Obj extends Record<Key, Value>,
  MapperObj extends MapperFunctionsObject<Obj>
>(
  obj: Obj,
  mappers?: Partial<MapperObj>,
) =>
  Object.keys(obj).reduce<Obj>(
    (acc, key) => {
      if (typeof obj[key] !== 'function') {
        return acc;
      }

      const func = obj[key];
      const mapper = mappers?.[key];

      acc[key] = withLogging(
        logger,
        component,
        subcomponent ? `${subcomponent}.${key}` : key,
      )(func, mapper);

      return acc;
    },
    { ...obj },
  );
```

Which does exactly what I need to, as in when I do the following:

```js
const create = (id: string) => 'value'

const repository = withGenericLogging(
  log,
  'Module',
  'Submodule'
)(
  { create },
  { create: id => 'mappedId' },
);
```

The types for `{ create: id => 'mappedId' }` will be inferred properly, and will be `{ create: (id: string) => unknown }` (as intended)